# Unable to remote connect to MySQL

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, remote-access

I've set up a `MySQL` server on a `Compute 
Engine VMs`, Set up all of the required users, etc however I can't remotely connect.

I've opened the ports through firewall, given all the required permissions, made sure the server is running and just about every other method I've found so far. I checked the `my.ini` file (Using 8.0 on Windows 2012 R2) and found no 'bind-address' value or similar in the file.

I've assigned a static IP, ran:

```
"CREATE USER 'root'@'%' identified by 'password'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* to 'root'@'$';"
```

and I'm getting the error

```
Cannot connect to database server...
unable to connect to...
```

any help to do with remote connection appreciated :)

Comment: Your error message is not complete. Also, show the exact program command line that you are using. Most likely you have incorrectly configured the firewall settings for your VM instance or you are not binding MySQL to the public interfaces.

Comment: Are you following [this documentation?](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/setup-mysql)